# How to stop the code if database value changed before a specific period

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and mySQL, in my `'users'` table, I have `HWID` value. With every login, the `HWID` updates. How do I limit their ability in login to only use 1 `HWID` in 3 days? If `HWID` got updated with a different value within 3 days, it stops them from logging in?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Do you store the last time they logged in?

Comment: Add a column with the time that the HWID was saved. Check if the current time is less than 3 days after that and the current ID is different.

Comment: Why not use another value other than `HWID`?

Comment: @Script47 I didn't really try something for now, I need an idea to do that mission.

Comment: @MarwanKhaled please, take the [tour].

Comment: Something like `lastlogin_column <= now() - interval 3 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that would be to have an additional field in your `users` table called something like `update_date` that keeps track of when the last time the `HWID` was updated. If the `update_date` field is still within 3 days of the last updated time, then do not let them log in.

If you provide some of your code we could take a look and work from there.